# Sencha touch 2.3.1 file upload not working xtype:filefield not working

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, extjs, sencha-touch

I am trying to upload an image using sencha touch 2.3.1. After googling I found that I can use xtype:fileinput and xtype:filefield for capturing files from both gallery and camera.

Here are the contents of items array in my View

```
items : [
            {
               xtype : 'filefield',
               name : 'coverPicImage',
               accept: 'image',
               label : 'Cover pic'
            }
        ]
```

Here is the controller

```
config: {
    refs :{
        coverPicFile : 'uploadform filefield[name=coverPicImage]',
        submitButton : 'uploadform button[action=submit]'
     },
    control: {
        submitButton:   {
            tap : 'onSubmit'
        }
    }
}

onSubmit : function(){
    var coverPicInput = this.getCoverPicFile().input;
    var files = coverPicInput.dom.files;
}
```

The problem is this.getCoverPicFile().input is undefined. this.getCoverPicFile() returns a class.

**If I change filefield to fileinput it works fine**.

The error which I get is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of undefined
```

Is there any reason for why this is not working with filefield

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I lost a lot of time on this, in the end i managed to get the pic and upload it to server in base64 format. [This tutorial](http://moduscreate.com/device-camera-access-with-sencha-touch/) worked for me.
Dont be fooled my the title this tutorial allow you to select the file/images from local filesystem.

Comment: This example is not using xtype:filefield. I was able to upload the image using xtype:fileinput. I wanted to know why filefield is not working